# How to work with multiple inputs for LSTM in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to predict the water usage of a population.

I have 1 main input:

- Water volume

and 2 secondary inputs:

- Temperature
- Rainfall

In theory they have a relation with the water supply.

It must be said that each rainfall and temperature data correspond with the water volume. So this is a time series problem.

The problem is that I don't know how to use 3 inputs from just one .csv file, with 3 columns, each one for each input, as the code below is made. When I have just one input (e.g.water volume) the network works more or less good with this code, but not when I have more than one. (So if you run this code with the csv file below, it will show a dimension error).

Reading some answers from:

- [Time Series Prediction with LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks in Python with Keras](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)
- [Time Series Forecast Case Study with Python: Annual Water Usage in Baltimore](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecast-study-python-annual-water-usage-baltimore/)

it seems to be that many people have the same problem.

The code:

**EDIT:** Code has been updated

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import math

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - 1):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 2])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)



# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)


# load the dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('datos.csv', engine='python') 
dataset = dataframe.values

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67) 
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 3
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)  
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be  [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], look_back, 3))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0],look_back, 3))

# create and fit the LSTM network

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_dim=look_back))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history= model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.33, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=32)

# Plot training
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('pérdida')
plt.xlabel('época')
plt.legend(['entrenamiento', 'validación'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()

# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

# Get something which has as many features as dataset
trainPredict_extended = numpy.zeros((len(trainPredict),3))
# Put the predictions there
trainPredict_extended[:,2] = trainPredict[:,0]
# Inverse transform it and select the 3rd column.
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict_extended) [:,2]  
print(trainPredict)
# Get something which has as many features as dataset
testPredict_extended = numpy.zeros((len(testPredict),3))
# Put the predictions there
testPredict_extended[:,2] = testPredict[:,0]
# Inverse transform it and select the 3rd column.
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict_extended)[:,2]   


trainY_extended = numpy.zeros((len(trainY),3))
trainY_extended[:,2]=trainY
trainY=scaler.inverse_transform(trainY_extended)[:,2]


testY_extended = numpy.zeros((len(testY),3))
testY_extended[:,2]=testY
testY=scaler.inverse_transform(testY_extended)[:,2]


# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY, trainPredict))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY, testPredict))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, 2] = trainPredict

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, 2] = testPredict



#plot

 serie,=plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset)[:,2])  
prediccion_entrenamiento,=plt.plot(trainPredictPlot[:,2],linestyle='--')  
prediccion_test,=plt.plot(testPredictPlot[:,2],linestyle='--')
plt.title('Consumo de agua')
plt.ylabel('cosumo (m3)')
plt.xlabel('dia')
plt.legend([serie,prediccion_entrenamiento,prediccion_test],['serie','entrenamiento','test'], loc='upper right')
```

This is the csv file I have created, if it helps.

[datos.csv](https://pastebin.com/qZv5HygU)

After changing the code, I fixed all the errors, but I'm not really sure about the results. This is a zoom in the prediction plot:
[image: Zoom on plot]

which shows that there is a "displacement" in the values predicted and in the real ones. When there is a max in the real time series, there is a min in the forecast for the same time, but it seems like it corresponds to the previous time step.

Comment: so when you go from 1 input to 3 columns you still use 

'trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))'

but create 3 window features? if you create 3 window features the second argument to '.reshape' should be 3

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I had 3 on the second argument but I changed the code to test the net with another data (just one column input). Anyway, it doesn't work with 3. This error appears: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: The displacement could be due to the lag in predicting maximums/minimums given the randomness in the data.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change

```
a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0]
```

To

```
a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
```

If you want the 3 features in your training data.

Then use

```
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(look_back,3)))
```

To specify that you have `look_back` time steps in your sequence, each with 3 features.

It should run

**EDIT :**

Indeed, `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()`'s function : `inverse_transform()` takes an input which has the same shape as the object you fitted. So you need to do something like this :

```
# Get something which has as many features as dataset
trainPredict_extended = np.zeros((len(trainPredict),3))
# Put the predictions there
trainPredict_extended[:,2] = trainPredict
# Inverse transform it and select the 3rd column.
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict_extended)[:,2]
```

I guess you will have other issues like this below in your code but nothing that you can't fix :) the ML part is fixed and you know where the error comes from. Just check the shapes of your objects and try to make them match.

Comment: This answer is really good, I didn't realised that I was selecting just the first (zero) column. It has partially solved the problem, because now I can do the training but I get another error: ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (817,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (817,3)  in line 72. So I suposse there is an error in the matrix shapes.

Comment: More or less. But I got some other errors that I have fix, but I don't know if it is normal to get a prediction that seems to be "displaced" on time...anyway I don't get a good prediction. I'm going to edit the code, in order you can run it if you want to.

Comment: well, what did you expect, it is predicting the next move based on the current situation, of course it will always be a little late, it can't predict big spikes in advance, there is randomness in your data. It ingests the big, unpredictable moves at the next step and then adjusts it's next prediction... We can talk about this in a chat if you want but I think this question is solved :)

Answer (score -1):

You can change what you are optimizing, for maybe better results. For example, try predicting binary 0,1 if there will be a 'spike up' for the next day. Then feed the probability of a 'spike up' as a feature to predict the usage itself.