# LSTM many to one prediction using keras input shape

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, keras, lstm

Initially, i have a csv file with 6 columns: date,electricity consumption and 4 other climate features that have an impact on the consumption ( such as temperature, humidity etc)

So far, i can run my LSTM on the consumption column only , and it has given me very accurate results, but i need to feed my LSTM with the other features. I tried to modify the python code according to previous comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532386/how-to-work-with-multiple-inputs-for-lstm-in-keras/45277707#45277707) but still having a reshape error.

here s my code after some modifications:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import math

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
  dataX, dataY = [], []
  for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - 1):
    a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
    dataX.append(a)
    dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 2])
  return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)


  # fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)


# load the dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('out_meteo.csv', engine='python') 
dataset = dataframe.values

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67) 
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 3
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)  
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be  [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], look_back, 3))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0],look_back, 3))

# create and fit the LSTM network

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(look_back,3)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history= model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.33, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32)



# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

# Get something which has as many features as dataset
trainPredict_extended = numpy.zeros((len(trainPredict),3))
# Put the predictions there
trainPredict_extended[:,2] = trainPredict
# Inverse transform it and select the 3rd column.
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict_extended)[:,2]

print(trainPredict)
# Get something which has as many features as dataset
testPredict_extended = numpy.zeros((len(testPredict),3))
# Put the predictions there
testPredict_extended[:,2] = testPredict[:,0]
# Inverse transform it and select the 3rd column.
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict_extended)[:,2]   


trainY_extended = numpy.zeros((len(trainY),3))
trainY_extended[:,2]=trainY
trainY=scaler.inverse_transform(trainY_extended)[:,2]


testY_extended = numpy.zeros((len(testY),3))
testY_extended[:,2]=testY
testY=scaler.inverse_transform(testY_extended)[:,2]


# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY, trainPredict))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY, testPredict))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, 2] = trainPredict

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, 2] = testPredict

 # plot baseline and predictions
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.show()
```

the error i am getting is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "desp.py", line 48, in <module>
    trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], look_back, 3))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",  line 232, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",  line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 35226 into shape (1957,3,3)
```

Please note that I am still a newbie and that the reshape concept is still a little ambigus to me.

Comment: this is the answer: cannot reshape array of size 35226 into shape (1957,3,3)

Comment: but ok, show me please shapes of the trainX and testX.

Comment: trainX.shape= (1957, 3, 6)
testX.shape= (963, 3, 6)

Comment: you see the issue? you have a tensor with shape (1957, 3, 6), which is equal to  1957 * 3 * 6 = 35226. And you want to reshape your tensor to a new shape (1957,3,3) = 17613. So, the problem is your new dimensions are not fit. As a work around, I suggest to remove all reshape functions. And change input shape into (look_back, 6)

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question I would suggest to check about multidimensional lists / arrays in python / numpy.

Also, here is a link to explanation regarding shapes of the tensor in Keras

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2045

Answer (score 0):

here is my final code that takes all of the columns

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import math

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
   dataX, dataY = [], []
   for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - 1):
     a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
     dataX.append(a)
     dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 2])
   return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)


 # fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

#load the dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('out_meteo.csv', engine='python') 
dataset = dataframe.values

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.7) 
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 3
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)  
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)


# create and fit the LSTM network

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(look_back,6)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history= model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.33, nb_epoch=15, batch_size=15)

# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

print(trainPredict)

# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY, trainPredict))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY, testPredict))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

 # plot baseline and predictions
plt.plot((dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.show()
```

So far, it works well on all of my csv columns, i have also removed many lines ( reshape , MinMAxScaler transformation) but still cannot visualize my final data correctly ( with real values), it shows really small values or a strict line.
the return train and test score for this dataset are respectively 0.03 and 0.05

Answer (score 0):

Before plotting, try to do

```
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
```