# is this correctly work on predict next value in keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

here is my code

```
...
look_back = 20
train_size = int(len(data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(data) - train_size

train = data[0:train_size]
test = data[train_size:len(data)]
x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
y_train=np.repeat(y_train.reshape(-1,1), 20, axis=1).reshape(-1,20,1)
y_test=np.repeat(y_test.reshape(-1,1), 20, axis=1).reshape(-1,20,1)
...
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
p = model.predict(x_test)
```

and I want to predict the next value So,
`predictions = model.predict(x_train)` and shape is `(62796, 20, 1)`

and I coded the following site [how to use the Keras model to forecast for future dates or events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760472/how-to-use-the-keras-model-to-forecast-for-future-dates-or-events)

```
future = []
currentStep = predictions[-20:, :, :] # -20 is last look_back number

for i in range(10):
    currentStep = model.predict(currentStep)
    future.append(currentStep)
```

in this code future's result is

[image: 1]

but `p = model.predict(x_test)`'s [:4000] result is

[image: 2]

The difference between the two results is very large.

is this right way to Predict the next value??

I don't know where it went wrong or the code went wrong.

I hope for your opinion.

full source is https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/654f70bd1fb9c4f7d5bdb21ddcb588ab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you are trying to predict next value using lstm.
So here you have to reshape your  input data correctly to reflect the time steps and features.

```
model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
```

instead of this code you have to write :

```
model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(look_back,x)))
```

> x = input features in your training data.

I guess this article will help to moderate your code and predict the future value:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532386/how-to-work-with-multiple-inputs-for-lstm-in-keras)

This article will help you to understand more about how to predict future value:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms/50235563#50235563)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods you can try. There is no one right way at the moment. You can train a seperate model for predicting t+1, t+2 ... t+n. One LSTM model predicts t+1 while another predicts t+n. That is called a DIRMO strategy.

Your strategy (recursive strategy) is particularly risky because the model can propagate the error through multiple time horizons.

You can find a good comparison of alternative strategies in this paper.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417412000528?via%3Dihub